# Can I hide a section if there are no reviews in Woocomemerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, review

In woocommerce, if a product has no reviews, there is a section I call "ID: #reviewssummary" and I want to hide this section within the product page.

I want to do this because I only have people who buy products leave comments using the "my account" page and not in the product page.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you check this:
Using `get_comments()`

```
$args = array ('post_type' => 'product', 'post_id' => get_the_ID());
$comments = get_comments( $args );
if(empty($comments)) {
    echo 'No Reviews Yet';
}
```

Another way `$product->get_review_count()`

```
global $product;
if ($product && $product->get_review_count() === 0) {
    echo 'No Reviews Yet';
}
```